# Public Shared Function SQL Query, class issue when try to include DDL in WHERE clause

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Not familiar with Shared functions, so I'm not just looking for the answer but also a explanation on how this class works. The issue that I'm having is within my SQL query where I'm trying to find WHERE ID = ddldropdown.selectedValue. I'm unable to access the ddldropdown, due to it not being in a shared class.

```
Public Shared Function HEvents() As List(Of \[Events\])
Dim events As List(Of \[Events\]) = New List(Of \[Events\])()
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("USC").ConnectionString
Dim Query As String = "SELECT *  From Cal " &
WHERE CalId = " & GetCalId() & " "
"UNION ALL " &
"Select 0 As EventId, Description As EventName," &
"Format((CAST(Convert(DateTimeOffset, HolidayDate) As datetime)), 'd', 'en-US') AS StartDate," &
"Format((CAST(Convert(DateTimeOffset, HolidayDate) As datetime)), 'd', 'en-US') AS EndDate," &
"'Red' AS Color," &
"'White' AS TextColor," &
"'12:00 AM' AS StartTime," &
"'11:59 PM' AS EndTime " &
"From \[Darkside\].\[USC\].\[dbo\].\[Holidays\]"




 Public Function GetCalId() As String
        Dim calId As String = ddldropdown.selectedValue.
        Return calId
    End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: "The issue that I'm having" - and the issue you are having is???

Comment: I'm unable to access the ddldropdown, due to it not being in a shared class

Comment: Please [edit] that clarification into your question.

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag, because its clearly not related to your issue.

Comment: then make it public

Comment: _Not familiar with Shared functions_: Then it seems that you should refer to the official documentation to learn about them. _I'm unable to access the ddldropdown, due to it not being in a shared class_: Where did you get this code? I recommend you learn the basics of computer programming by finding some tutorials. You can also deepen your understanding by refering to the MS documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this all code behind on the same page?

If yes, then remove the shared option, since that means "static" or that the page class does not have to be created. So a static class (or static method/sub/function) of a class means you can call and use that code, and do so without a instance of that class having to be created or exist in code.

Thus, in this example, the function HEvents can try to call any other code in the given web page, but it will not have use of any valid controls or control references. So, if that function is in fact in code behind in a given page, then declare it as public, but not "static" (shared). So "shared" means static in vb land. Remove the shared declare, and your code should work.

I would if you are a looking to create a "general" routine to fill out any listbox or combo box on a web form? flip the code around, and have the code ehind on that page call the routine, but ALSO pass the control in question. As such, then the routine you call could in theory be static. (but, it would not matter either way).

So, flip this around, and pass the combo box (dropdown list) to the routine

eg this:

```
 Call MyCombo(me.ddldropdown)
```

And then this for the sub or function:

```
 Public Sub MyCombo(cbo as DropDownList)

    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("USC").ConnectionString

     Dim Query As String = "SELECT *  From Cal " &
        WHERE CalId = " & cbo.SelectItem.Value

      .etc .etc .etc
 End Sub
```

So, regardless of the final goal, you can pass a control from code behind on a web page to any routine, including a so called shared (means static) routine.

As noted, if the code is on the same page code behind, then just remove the shared declare.